# JavaFX Gluon Mobile iOS build exception for createIpa

Tags: ios, gluon, gluon-mobile, robovm, javafxports

I try to launch Gradle task `createIpa` from my project an getting this error:

```
...
Warning: java.awt.print.Paper is a phantom class!
Warning: sun.util.calendar.Era is a phantom class!
Warning: sun.util.calendar.CalendarDate is a phantom class!
Warning: sun.util.calendar.CalendarSystem is a phantom class!
Warning: sun.util.calendar.LocalGregorianCalendar is a phantom class!
:HelloWorldApp:createIpa FAILED

Execution failed for task ':HelloWorldApp:createIpa'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '/Volumes/RoboVM RAM Disk/tmp/Users/HelloWorld/HelloWorldApp/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/HelloWorldApp' does not exist
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file? Did it work for you before, or have you deployed successfully to iOS before?
Try to run `./gradlew --info clean createIpa` and post any possible exception?

Comment: It's the first time I'm doing this.
`build.gradle` and console log are here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1L5T-PdUwCg8a3Le2qo3VbyhnwEN_WAuX?usp=sharing

Comment: That log is from running `./gradlew --info clean createIpa`? I see it took 25 minutes, the first time it has to compile everything. The next run should take way less than that. Are you using a RAM disk? Can you try without it?